# What are the 9 mountains and 8 seas?

Tags: one-piece

So we have all seen Zoro boast.

> Over the 9 mountains and 8 seas... Throughout the world itself... There is nothing I cannot cut.

Now it made me wonder, which mountains and what seas was he referring to?

Comment: Wow this is a quality question

Answer (score 12):

Some of Zoro's attacks are named after Buddhism like 36/72/108 Pondo Hou

[One Piece Wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Roronoa_Zoro/Misc.):

> the 36/72/108 Pondo Hou, is a reference to the 36 passions of Buddhism

So most likely Zoro is referring to the Buddhist legend of [Sumeru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumeru) the central world-mountain in Buddhist cosmology.

I'm not an Buddhism expert but in the Wikipedia article about [Sumeru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumeru) you see a list of 9 mountains and 8 seas, so since Zoro likes Buddhism and Hindu references in his attacks, it's most like Oda made a reference to this.

Answer (score 11):

Mintri's answer is right, but for the sake of having an in-universe/joke answer:

8 Seas:

1. North Blue
2. South Blue
3. East Blue
4. West Blue
5. Paradise (Grand line, 1st half)
6. New World (Grand line, 2nd half)
7. Left Calm Belt
8. Right Calm Belt

9 Mountains:

1. [Reverse Mountain](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Reverse_Mountain)
2. [Drum Rockies](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Drum_Rockies)
3. [Marijois' Mountain Range](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mariejois#Location)
4. [Mt Colubo](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mt._Colubo)
5. [Punk Hazard's Mountain Range](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Punk_Hazard)

With the remaining 4 yet to be seen.

Comment: well isn't the redline a mountain too :D

Comment: I would argue that, since the redline is one continuous mass of land, it wouldn't be considered a mountain. Possibly a mountain range at best, but more like a really high continent otherwise.

Comment: @Thebluefish Actually, although it's a single mass of land, it has high areas, low areas and certain parts are considered to be 'islands' that in fact have their own climates, just like those along the grand line.

Comment: @Mintri Both reverse mountain and the mountain marijois is located on are a part of the red line, but they're the most significant because they exist where the grand line crosses the red line.

Comment: I'm genuinely surprised this was accepted as the answer.

Comment: yeah, beat me <.<

Comment: @Mintri I enjoyed and upvoted both answers, but I was indeed looking for an in-universe answer, that's why I accepted this one. Doesn't mean yours was wrong though.

Comment: @PeterRaeves but this answer is nowhere proofed right and as Pharap said, more of a joke answer than a real one. I thought this network has the goal to be as correct as possible

Comment: @Mintri ofcourse it is. But unless zoro tells us himself this seems to be a legit answer as Pharap mentiond the 8 seas previously mentioned in one piece and 5 (out of 9) mentioned mountains. I dont see how one could be more correct than that (unless he wrote all 9 mountains). Or am i missing something?

Comment: @PeterRaeves hm okay, we enter the realm of interpretation now :D 
IMO an answer should be more reasoned and proofed by sources. 
also in a logic ways it doesn't make any sense for zorro to refere to any in universe places which some of them he never saw when all other attacks are clearly reffered to religions things. Do ou really think, oda would break this rule after 18 years?

Comment: @Mintri I guess. I completely agree oda refers to bhuddism, while Zoro might not cos I dont remember buddhism being specifically mentioned. But since this is a community driven site, ill unaccept and let the people decide which answer they like best.

Comment: That and tbh when I asked the question I was just curious about the geography of the OP world, not about Oda's symbolism. But we will see.

Comment: @PeterRaeves i never said that zorro is a buddhist, just that his attacks are named after some budhhistic references but not all, for example Asura is name after a Hindu demon. i don't know any explanation why zorro knows all these name references but oda knows them for sure und uses them for his attacks. 
i could make a list with all attacks that have religion references to prove them :D 
also when you are curious about the one piece world, then that answer would answer you're question, but i think that it is somehow asked unluckly then :D

Comment: @Mintri I know what you were saying. The point is that in-universe Buddhism has not been recognised as a religion despite the fact it is referenced by Zoro's attacks and Sengoku's Epithet. The same for Hinduism. The OP said that he was after an in-universe explanation, and the attack names' true origins can't be easily explained in-universe. Besides the true explanations for all the references in Zoro's attacks can be found on the Wiki: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Santoryu

Answer (score 2):

Nine mountains and eight seas ［九山八海］ ( kusen-hakkai): The mountains and seas that constitute the world, according to ancient Indian cosmology. The nine mountains are Mount Sumeru at the center of the world and eight concentric mountain ranges that surround it. Eight concentric seas separate these mountain ranges. According to The Dharma Analysis Treasury, the eight circular mountain ranges are, from the innermost out, Yugamdhara, Īshādhāra, Khadiraka, Sudarshana, Ashvakarna, Vinataka, Nimimdhara, and Chakravāda-parvata. All these mountain ranges are made of gold except the outermost, Chakravāda-parvata, also known as the Iron Encircling Mountains, which is made of iron. Mount Sumeru and the eight mountain ranges are each separated from one another by a sea. The distance between Mount Sumeru and Mount Yugamdhara is eighty thousand yojanas. The inner seven seas are of fresh water, while the outermost sea, just inside the iron mountain range, is salty. In this sea are four continents—Pūrvavideha in the east, Jambudvīpa in the south, Aparagodānīya in the west, and Uttarakuru in the north. See also four continents.

From: http://www.nichirenlibrary.org/en/dic/Content/N/68