# Why is All Blue not part of the 8 Seas?

Tags: one-piece

While exploring this site, I came across this particular question: [What are the 9 mountains and 8 seas?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20202/what-are-the-9-mountains-and-8-seas)

In the answers however, I did not see anyone mention All Blue. So my question is why is All Blue not a part of the 8 Seas that Zoro mentions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because All Blue is not a sea in itself, but the point of union of all 4 great seas where every kind of fish of every sea can be found.

Source: [One Piece wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/All_Blue)