# Where is All Blue located?

Tags: one-piece

After reading [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/22379/6166), I looked through some One Piece world maps as you can see below and they made me wonder. Where would [All Blue](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/All_Blue) even be at? All Blue is supposedly the place where the four seas meet.

> The All Blue is a mystical sea of legend, rumoured to be the only place in the world where the North, South, East, and West seas meet.

Since the four seas are separated from each other by the Grand and Red line, how and where would they be able to meet? Where would All Blue be at?

[image: enter image description here!]
[image: enter image description here!]

---

<sub>There is even [this interactive world map](http://khooz.com/) if you would be interested.</sub>

Comment: I think this will be answered later when maybe Nami will show us a new map, for the New World. We cannot predict where is located.

Also if you read in the wiki:

Upon reaching Mermaid Cove in Fishman Island, Sanji exclaims to the crew that "he has found the All Blue there"... However, due to Fishman Island being antipodal to Reverse Mountain as well as one of two connecting routes between Paradise and The New World, it is theoretically possible for the four seas to converge on that place.

Comment: It hasn't been revealed yet. Sanji thought it was Fishman Island for a moment.

Answer (score 3):

There is no canon or non-canon answer from the One Piece universe.  Sanji referred to a lake on Fishman island as his All Blue but that was not serious (I think). Until Oda says, we don't know.

We could speculate it could be reverse mountain, or a bay at Raftel, or a cavern deep underground, or Vegapunk's research aquarium on the moon, or an alternative dimension (an island ate a devil fruit?), or ..... The point is that Oda is very creative.  It could be many things as a result.

Comment: +1 I would love to see an island eat a Devil Fruit! Thinking about it, it should not even be impossible. If we can have gas eat a Devil Fruit, why not a mountain.

Comment: Portal portal? Turtle turtle? Gold gold?

Comment: Well it has to be a zoan fruit though, or nothing will happen until the mountain *dies* and the fruit reborns. Not sure how a mountain could die though.

Comment: @peterraeves Probably. Otherwise, it would make more sense for the consumer to be a plant with a massive root system resulting in unexplainable phenomenon all around the island. If portals, this could means an all blue lake.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse Mountain. That's the only logical option right now - the currents are formed from water of the four Blues so it connects on top of it. Maybe there aren't fish from all Blues, but there is definitely water from all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Episode 530 around 22:41 Hody Jones says that "We will take the center of the world, Fishman island". Fishman Island should be all blue, but then again Fishman island is deep down...

Answer (score 0):

The most predictable location would most likely be reverse mountain. After all, that is the only viewable location in which all the Blues meet. It instead could also be a deep lake that has underwater currents moving through it from the Blues through caves.